What is meant by Static Dispatch Restrictions?
So, I was going through LLVM-MCA and trying to understand the different metrics/views that it provides. As part of the extra statistics that MCA provides, I came across the Dynamic Dispatch Stall Cycle Table, where they talk about "Static Restrictions on Dispatch Group". What exactly does it mean and what are the implications of this restriction ?
I tried searching on the internet about it, but I couldn't find any blog/website that spoke about it.

Dispatch can mean either sending a uop (or instruction) from the scheduler to an execution unit (Intel terminology, others call this "issue"), or sending it from the front-end (fetch / decode etc. which happens in-order) to the back end (allocate/rename into the ROB (reorder buffer) and scheduler), which is what Intel calls "issue", most other computer-architecture folks call "dispatch".  Static I'd assume means applying all the time, or based on fixed hardware layout.  I don't know precisely what LLVM-MCA means by that.

In the source code it maps to HWStallEvent::DispatchGroupStall which is annotated with Generic stall events generated by the Scheduler. If you follow the code you end up here where the stat is incremented if hasResourceHazard(RM, IR) is true. So it's likely to collect a stall due to some resource (e.g. an entry in the StoreBuffer) not being available. In such cases, a debug line is ...

... printed (see here).
